# How to properly apply a DataTrigger binding inside a WPF style for a different component type?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm still a little green when it comes to WPF. I'm currently working on a WPF form that has several text boxes on it. Each of those TextBoxes are paired with a TextBlock sitting in the same x,y coord, acting as GhostText. Once you click inside the TextBox the GhostText disappears.

Below is an example of how the binding was originally setup in the form's XAML (this same code is duplicated for all text boxes thus the reasoning behind using a style) :

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Width="40" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name= "RecordMinutesTextBox" Padding="12,5,5,0" Text ="{Binding RecordMinute}"  Margin="0,25,5,1" PreviewTextInput="CheckNumberValidation" Background="{Binding ElementName=FireWashingtonResponseTimeReport,Path=DataContext.RequiredFieldColor}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="40"  IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="MIN" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="DarkGray" Margin="8,25,0,1"                               >
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=RecordMinutesTextBox}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

*Note the name of one of the many text boxes,"RecordMinutesTextBox", used as the ElementName for the DataTrigger Binding.

Here is the code from inside my WPF Style template:

```
<Style x:Key="MinuteAndSecondsGhostText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=??WhatDoIPutHere??}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>enter code here
```

So my question really comes down to this. What should I use in the DataTrigger Binding as the ElementName for this style? Considering that I have multiple TextBoxes with different names on my form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ThomasBomans I appreciate the edit suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I give you an idea... and you can change your codes base on it.

In my following sample you see the `TextBlock` shows state of `IsFocused` property of the `TextBox`. So you can put the pair of your elements in a parent like `StackPanel` and access to properties of one child in another child by `RelativeSource` instead of `ElementName`...

Just put this codes in your window and `focus` in `TextBox`, What you see inside the `TextBlock`?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White"  Margin="20">

 <TextBox Text="" Name="TextBox" Background="DarkSalmon" Width="100" Height="30"/>

 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Children[0].IsFocused,
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                          AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}"
               Margin="20,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

---

**Edit:**

Base on my above idea you can use `RelativeSource` instead of `ElementName` to resolve your problem like the following sample:

```
<Style x:Key="MinuteAndSecondsGhostText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Children[0].Text,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                              AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And in your `Window` body:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Pair1" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White"  Margin="20">
    <!--TextBox should be first child of StackPanel-->
    <TextBox Text="" Name="TextBox1" Background="DarkSalmon" Width="100" Height="30"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Sample Text" Style="{StaticResource MinuteAndSecondsGhostText}" Margin="20,0"/>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel x:Name="Pair2" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White"  Margin="20">
    <!--TextBox should be first child of StackPanel-->
    <TextBox Text="" Name="TextBox2" Background="DarkSalmon" Width="100" Height="30"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Sample Text" Style="{StaticResource MinuteAndSecondsGhostText}" Margin="20,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm trying it out right now. I'll let you know if it does what I need.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't resolve my issue. Using the text property in the TextBlock in this way removes my Ghost Text functionality. The code that I need to figure out is related to the DataTrigger for the TextBlock.

Comment: You wrote: _Once you click inside the TextBox the GhostText disappears._ Fisrt please tell me **Is it what you want?** If this is what you want then use `RelativeSource` instead of `ElementName` similar my codes. I bound `IsFocused` property of the first child (`TextBox`) to the `Text` property of the `TextBlock`. You can bind `IsFocused` to `Visibility` property by a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`. Do you need more help to implement this?

Comment: The code I have "works" as intended without the style. By implementing the text property as you suggested breaks the functionality I already have and desire. The text property for my text block is used to show the ghosted text. As stated before, I'm attempting to rewrite the DataTrigger of the text block; allowing usage for any text box component with the applied style. Therefore, your solution unfortunately is not applicable to my situation.

Comment: The idea is using `RelativeSource` and `Path=Children[0]` ! Anyway, I append new sample to my answer to help you directly.